# Generating heatmap for vgg16 with custom top layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras, heatmap, conv-neural-network, imagenet

As the title said, I created a simple 2-class CNN with the VGG16 imagenet pre-trained weights as the bottom layers, all of this using Python with Keras. I'm now trying to visualise the feature selection process  with the heatmap generation yet the solutions that I think I can implement are designed for the regular 1000-classes model. What should I do to make it work?

EDIT: I'm including some bits of the code that I think might be relevant:

```
#Loading vgc16 model
vgg16 = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
#vgg16.summary()
start = datetime.datetime.now()
model = Sequential()  
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))  
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.03))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.03))
model.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

And below is the training part which uses the vgg16 bottom layers to generate the feature files from the three data sets:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])  

history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels,  
      epochs=7,
      batch_size=batch_size,  
      validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))  

model.save(top_model_weights_path)  

(eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate(  
 validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Comment: always share a reproducible code example.

Comment: I added two bits of the code that I replicated for this try, I hope they're significant to help answer my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use keras_vis for visualization of the feature maps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from vis.visualization import visualize_cam

for modifier in [None, 'guided', 'relu']:
    plt.figure()
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.suptitle("vanilla" if modifier is None else modifier)
    for i, img in enumerate([img1, img2]):    
        # 20 is the imagenet index corresponding to `ouzel`
        grads = visualize_cam(model, layer_idx, filter_indices=20, 
                              seed_input=img, backprop_modifier=modifier)        
        # Lets overlay the heatmap onto original image.    
        jet_heatmap = np.uint8(cm.jet(grads)[..., :3] * 255)
        ax[i].imshow(overlay(jet_heatmap, img))
```

You can find the examples: https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/blob/master/examples/vggnet/attention.ipynb

Comment: I haven't been able to make it work with the custom model. This is designed for vgg16 and I can't quite get it right. Also, I'm using tf-keras-vis instead